# arcpy.mapping.AddLayer won't show up in TOC

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, arcgis-10.3, layers

**UPDATE: I am able to save the progress, and make the added layer actually show up in the TOC, by using mxd.saveACopy rather than mxd.save():**

`mxd.saveACopy(r"W:\for\RSI\DKL\General_User_Data\gamos\Projects\01_Tenures_Mobile_Map\Highway_intersections_2.mxd")`

**The downside is this way requires me to create a new .mxd, rather than save to an existing .mxd**

---

I am trying to add a layer file to the TOC in using the arcpy.mapping.AddLayer method in Python, but it won't show up:

```
arcpy.mapping.AddLayer(df, lyr, "TOP")
arcpy.RefreshActiveView(),arcpy.RefreshTOC() 
layers = arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd) #Returns the object list of layers
print"Here are the layers in the TOC:"
print"========================================"
for layer in layers:
    print layer.name
```

`df` and `lyr` are objects, `"TOP"` is the position it should be inserted.

After I do addLayer, I grab the ListLayers object from the mxd, then print out all the individual layers. It's there - so why can't I see it in the TOC in ArcMap ??

Here is how I grab my mxd and df objects, add the Layer, and (attempt) to save the .mxd:

```
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(r"W:\for\RSI\DKL\General_User_Data\gamos\Projects\01_Tenures_Mobile_Map\Finding_FSR_highway_intersections.mxd")
print (str(mxd) + " extracted OK")

#df = mxd.activeDataFrame
df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd, "Layers")[0]
print (str(df) + " extracted OK")

arcpy.mapping.AddLayer(df, lyr, "TOP") 

arcpy.RefreshActiveView()
arcpy.RefreshTOC()
mxd.save() #this will run inside the script OK, will run from an external script only if the mxd is closed ???
```

Comment: You are missing a quote mark in your first line - `TOP"`

Comment: Have you saved the MXD?

Comment: No - I get:
`IOError: MapDocObject: Unable to save.`
This may be part of the problem for sure..

Comment: Can you add the line of your `mxd` assignment to the code please?

Comment: @grego In addition to the mxd assignment line as requested above, please also include the line where you save the mxd

Comment: @Midavalo  I've updated the post to include these lines

Comment: You can't use `mxd.save()` on an open MXD unless you are running the script from within that MXD.  See the linked duplicate